# Scoring validation database based on estimates from test database in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, binomial-distribution

I divided my dataset into Test and Validation (50-50 split).

I ran glm function (link=binomial) on Test dataset and got the parameter estimates.

How do I score the Validation dataset based on these parameter estimates (beta) that I got from Test dataset. I know it has something to do with apply () but I am not sure. please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Split sample validation is highly unstable if $n < 20000$ and is not recommended.  If you do have an enormous test sample you can use the R `rms` package `val.prob` to do the validation and its help file will give you some pointers.  But better to look at the bootstrap and the `rms` `validate` and `calibrate` functions.

Comment: Thanks Frank, can you give me reference to the article that states " validation is highly unstable if n<20000 "....Thanks Frank.

Comment: You can run a simple simulation or refer to my book _Regression Modeling Strategies_.